# Generating and saving/downloading files with only javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I made a map editor for my game, the code is generated to a div with id "code". I am wondering how to generate a javascript file with this code. Obviously i have to get the text of the code div. `var code = $("#code").text();` will work. But now i want to generate and download javascript file with this code. Is it even possible to generate/download a file with only javascript or do i have to use php?

I want to choose the folder and the name manually.

Comment: And where do you plan to save the file? How should it be saved? Manually or automatically? In other words be more precise please

Comment: Manually - I want to choose the folder and the name of the file.

Comment: Who is "I" in your question? You as the author of the script, or the user using the script?

Comment: I am the author of the script, if by the script you mean the map editor. I just need to know how to download the file/if it is possible to download a file with javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer to your question is no.  For security reasons browsers are very careful to NOT allow Javascript to do pretty much anything with the filesystem.

Flash however has no such limitations; check out: https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify.  Of course, Flash has its own issues, such as the fact that mobile browsers tend to not support it (but since your use case is downloading a file, and mobile users probably won't be doing that, this might not be an issue for you).

Other than Downloadify (or a similar Flash-based solution) your only options are Java applets (you don't want to go down that road), browser plug-ins, or some sort of server-involvement (eg. as @Brad Christie described).

Comment: You're quite welcome (and thanks for being more informed than the average new SO user and accepting an answer without any explanation required :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have the power to prompt for a file save. Your best bet would be to dump it to a new window and display it to the user where they could save it should they chose (file->Save). Otherwise, you need to find a way to pass the necessary information to a PHP call and then PHP can serve it up with `Content-Disposition: attachment` and the client can be prompted to download the file.

Also, as machineghost just beat me to, you can use a plugin like flash to keep it client-side but it's still not plain JavaScript. But [Downloadify](https://github.com/dcneiner/Downloadify) does have that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can kinda do it, although you have poor control over suggesting the filename and file extension.

I wouldn't use this for a production website, but it seems to work.

```
function promptSave(data) {
    /*@cc_on @*/
    /*@if (@_jscript_version >= 4)
        //ie code here
        var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        var doc = iframe.contentWindow.document;
        doc.write(data);
        doc.execCommand('SaveAs', '', 'somefilename.txt');//only certain file extensions allowed
        document.body.removeChild(iframe);
        @else @*/
        // non ie code
        window.location = 'data:application/octet-stream;base64,' + window.btoa(data);
    /*@end @*/
}
var data = 'var jsFoo = {k:55};';
promptSave(data);
```

### **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3eQEX/)**

firefox is insistent on saving it as a `.part` file though.