# Javascript download image without server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

My setup is that I have a cd containing html pages with images. I would like the ability to save these images via a link or a button when it is pressed. I am not sure if this is even possible as I know you can do this by modifying headers, but I am looking for a javascript way as this needs to work with most browsers and with no server straight from the disk.

Any help and advice welcome.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server

Comment: This is for extremely inexperienced users. So a large button saying save is preferable.

Comment: What about opening the images in a new, maybe dynamically created window, explaining how to use the context menu?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14062914/generating-and-saving-downloading-files-with-only-javascript/